# How to disable git submodules when using git in Git subfolder

Tags: git, github

I have this structue:

```
c:\git-project>
c:\git-project\something\another-git-prject>
```

I want that all the git commands run from `another-git-project`, will be pushed to 1 repository. and all git command that run in `git-project` will be pushed to another repository.

In other words:

`another-git-project` will contain all the files of it's folder.
`git-project` will contain all the files in the both projects.

- I don't want to use submodules.

---

**In other words:**
I want that the parent `git` will see the child git, as a regular folder

I tried to do this

```
notepad .gitignore
something\another-git-prject\.git
^s
```

But it did not do the job

Comment: Ignoring it will do the job. It looks like your ignore rule might be wrong (it's relative to the git project directory, I don't think you should use the full path), and if `another-git-project` is already tracked it won't be ignored.

Comment: is there a `.gitmodules` file in git-project? If there is, try deleting it, maybe it will work.

Comment: The problem is, I think that git will recreate it automatically. And git will be misconfuse when I'm doing git status inside the "submodule"

Comment: Tried it - worked for me, have you tried deleting it?

Comment: Tested' and working. very interesting. Last time I tested it it didn't work.